# Slate Foundry : Modify parameter of a Dropdown programmatically

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

In Slate foundry, I would modify parameter of a Dropdown programmatically.
Change the display value or disable value. But it doesn't work.

My code

```
const select ={{w_selectEndMonthYear}}
select.selectedValue = "202201"
select.selectedDisplayValue = "January 2022"
select.disabled = true
console.log({{w_selectEndMonthYear}})
return {{w_selectEndMonthYear.selectedDisplayValue}}
```

in my console, I have

```
{selectedDisplayValue: 'January 2022', selectedValue: '202201', disabled: 'true'}
```

It seems good, but neither the return nor the display of the widget changed

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track - to template the selected value of a dropdown list programmatically you need to change to the `</>` tab of the dropdown widget configuration and use Handlebars to provide a *valid* default selection for *both* the the `selectedValue` and `selectedDisplayValue` parameter.

Note that you *cannot* set widget properties from inside a Slate Function. You need to *return* the value (or a json object with multiple values to reference) and then use a Handlebar statement in the widget configuration to template the appropriate values into the widget configuration.

You can read a bit about this in the context of *resetting* widget selection state to default values in [this section](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/best-practices-user-interaction/#resetting-selections-and-managing-default-values) of the documentation.

You can also search your Foundry instance for some helpful Slate tutorials - find the `Foundry Training and Resources` project and navigate to the `Reference Examples/App Building In Slate/1. Tutorials` folder to find a series of interactive Slate apps demonstrating the many patterns for using Handlebars, Functions, and other Slate components.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i via Functions, also to deliver the the content of dropdown.
Just a hint, to sort the content you need 'transformColumnSchemaToRowSchema' and 'transformRowSchemaToColumnSchema'

Here is a Slate JavaScript snippet for enabling/disabling a button:
Similar you could do this for drop-downs i think.

```
// Collect Inputs for Validation
// -----------------------------
var inputs = {
    UserID: _.trim(_.toUpper({{w_pD_AdmUserAdd_UserID.text}})),
    Foundry: _.trim({{w_pD_AdmUserAdd_Foundry.placeholder}}),
    NameFirst: _.trim(_.toUpper({{w_pD_AdmUserAdd_NameFirst.text}})),
    NameLast: _.trim(_.toUpper({{w_pD_AdmUserAdd_NameLast.text}})),
    Email: _.trim(_.toUpper({{w_pD_AdmUserAdd_Email.text}})),
    Team: {{w_pD_AdmUserAdd_Team.selectedValue}},
    Company: {{w_pD_AdmUserAdd_Company.selectedValue}}
}
// Initialize Variables
// --------------------
var disable = false;
var messages = [];
// Implement Form Validation Checks
// --------------------------------
// Check if all the required fields have a value
if (!(inputs.UserID &&
     inputs.Foundry &&
 inputs.NameFirst &&
 inputs.NameLast &&
     inputs.Email &&
     inputs.Team &&
     inputs.Company
    )){
disable = true;
messages.push("Please complete all required fields.");
}
var email_regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
if (inputs.Email && !email_regex.test(inputs.Email)){
messages.push('Please enter a valid email for "Email"')
disable = true;
}
var data_users = {{s_buyers.data}}
var index_email = data_users.str_email.indexOf(inputs.Email)

if (inputs.Email && index_email !== -1){
  disable = true;
  messages.push('This Email already exist')
}  
var index_userid = data_users.str_buyer_id.indexOf(inputs.UserID)
if (inputs.UserID && index_userid !== -1){
  disable = true;
  messages.push('This User ID already exist')
}
return {
inputs,
disable,
messages
}
```